# Rattling noise when accelerating in roundabouts

Tags: noise, steering, bearing

I have a 2007 Jaguar S-Type 2.7D version with the following problem:

When I'm inside a roundabout (with the wheels steered to the left direction) and I'm accelerating (moderate to high) I hear a rattling/scrapping noise coming from the right wheel area.

I checked and there's nothing touching the actual wheel/rubber, no visible damage.

The sound doesn't occur if I'm not accelerating (I tried this a couple of times, it's always smooth if I don't accelerate).

The car is RWD, so there are no half shafts connected to the front wheels. The right wheel bearing was replaced one year ago (with a cheap Chinese no-name one). Suspension bushings are fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, check the right wheel bearing...

Comment: If it's the bearing, wouldn't the rattling occur even if I'm not accelerating? This is my only concern, since there's no play or strange sound in the bearing when I'm rotating/checking the wheel by hand.

Comment: You could go to a isolated parking place and drive "snake lines" (swerving left and right on low speed, without putting someone, inclusive yourself, in danger). That is a common test to check for suspension damage. Why am I suggesting an suspension-check? I had a similar issue once: The stabilizer-bar shifted and rubbed against the frame.